# css not loading on site

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get basic css working on my site. This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" href="test.css" rel="stylesheet"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test">
        This is a test document.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This is how the files are laid out:

```
 + ask_site
     + index.php
     + test.css
```

I am running the newest version of XAMPP and have no idea what's going on. Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change following line

```
<style type="text/css" href="test.css" rel="stylesheet"></style>
```

to

```
<link type="text/css" href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```